# How to add a shortcut to the 'My Apps & Games' screen of the Google Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store, home-screen-shortcuts

I'm looking to create a shortcut that links straight to the 'My Apps & Games' screen of the Google Play Store.

Either that, or configure the Google Play Store to always open in the 'My Apps' screen.

I've downloaded and installed AnyCut 1.0 but I'm unable to find the activity for opening Play on that screen.

[AnyCut 1.0](http://www.freewarelovers.com/android/app/any-cut)

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need an app like [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsIm5ldC5kaW5nbGlzY2guYW5kcm9pZC50YXNrZXJtIl0.) than can assign actions with activity launches.  Create a New Task, name it, and Add an action.  Go to **System** → **Send Intent**.  Then fill out these fields:

- **Action**

  - `com.google.android.finsky.VIEW_MY_DOWNLOADS`
- **Package**

  - `com.android.vending`
- **Class**

  - `com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity`
- **Target**

  - Select "Activity"

Assign an icon from the lower right.  Leave Tasker.  On your desktop, create a new shortcut, Task Shortcut, and select the task you named.

Comment: No it doesn't. I just did this running 4.2.2

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with 4.0.3

Comment: You must've done something wrong then

Comment: Apologies, I tried again and it worked - found a few more instructions here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1582313
Previously I kept getting the error message "package not installed".

Comment: Works in Android 5.0 Lollipop.

Comment: Do you know of a legitimate link to QCustomShortcut?

Comment: Tasker works in Android 4.4.4, clarified the instructions.

Comment: Cool! Based on this Intent, is it possible to click the Update All button via an Intent?

Comment: Does this still work?  I don't see that `action` available in Google Play store.  If it's not in that app, in which app is the action located?

Answer (score 0):

*The following will work *only* in Android 7.1 and later:*

It should be possible to go directly to the My apps section of the Google Play Store by long pressing the Play Store icon and dragging the My apps shortcut out to the home screen.

It is described in this article on Android Police:
https://www.androidpolice.com/2016/12/28/android-7-1-tip-get-rid-play-store-home-screen-use-apps-shortcut-instead/

Comment: I added a note that this will only work in Android 7.1 and later.  If you know of any way to get it to work in earlier versions of Android, please add that too. :)